# NSTextField inside NSMenu -- doesn't interact or look as expected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm attempting to create a log-in window inside an NSMenu (attached to the an NSStatusItem in the menu bar).

I have blank NSMenuItems in the menu. I then set the views of the menu items to NSTextFields.

It ends up looking like this:

[image]

The textfields also interact strangely. Clicking on them only gives them focus (so you can enter text) about 30% of the time.

So, I'm wondering:

-How do do I make these look better? How do I control the padding, etc?

-What's with the clicking behavior I described above? Typing only works 30% of the time.

-Are there any other apps that use such a statusbar item as a field? I'd like to take a look.

Comment: Don't do this please. It's very bad UI design. Menus are not meant to take the keyboard's focus.

Comment: Is your complaint with the UI of logging-in in the menubar, or with using an NSMenu? Spotlight, for example, is designed for taking keyboard focus...

Comment: That doesn't mean you should attempt to do the same thing. Spotlight can be called upon frequently and has no other system-wide user interface; the user is unlikely to log in to his/her account repeatedly.

Comment: It's an app that exists entirely as a menu-bar item (no windows, no dock icon).

Comment: Jonathon, I disagree.  Editing menu items right in the menu itself is entirely appropriate, and we've been doing it that way in Interface Builder since the very beginning.

Comment: Again, Interface Builder is a very specialized case--you're editing in the menus because the menus themselves are the things being edited.

Comment: In this case, you really should present a modal alert for the (usually) one-time task of login. Store the user's credentials in the keychain, and refer back to them on subsequent sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your actual question instead of discussing the UI design...

**Alternative:**
Consider using the `MAAttachedWindow` project from Matt Gemmel:
Download the `use an MAAttachedWindow with an NSStatusItem` example.

**Link:**
http://mattgemmell.com/source/index.html

**Quickly created example:**
[image: Screenshot Login Window]

**Used controls:**
- NSTextField (Focus:`None` DrawsBackground:`No` TextColor:`White`)
- NSButton (Bezel:`Recessed`)
- NSLabel (TextColor:`White`)

Comment: Additional [link](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem/) to original blog post.

Comment: Thank you! Looks good. I'll have to decide whether to use this or do a NSWindow based login.